# Re-Arranging file array contents using Java

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have a File array where i have list of file names from a folder.

**e.g.**

```
File file = new File("/path");
File[] arr = file.listFiles();
```

So my **arr** has all file names inside  file path.

Say **arr**[folder1 , Folder2, Folder3].

Also i have a **String array list** which contains ( Folder3 , Folder1 , Folder2).

I need to change the **arr** contents as per **arrrayList** order.

(i.e) after processing my **arr** will have [ Folder3 , Folder1 , Folder2].

I need to do it because , i have to read folders based on certain hierarchy.

am new to this please help how can i achieve it.

Comment: Have you written any code to achieve this yet? If so, what problems did you encounter? Without showing your efforts to accomplish this your question may get closed.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Is there any rule, which you'd like the files to be sorted on, i.e. names, extensions etc.?

Comment: I tnink you need some mechanism like a filter(based on size,creation date, etc.), or something like that to build needed hierarchy.

Also you may sort first array and give an emmulated duplicate path array on you FS.

Comment: Please show us the code, which 'processes' your `arr` and what your **String array list** is. And please explain your question more detailed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the folder names as a String list in the desired order, why do you use File.listFiles()?

Just create the File objects from the names in the order they are listed, like this:

```
List< String > arrayList = Arrays.asList("Folder3", "Folder1", "Folder2");

File parent = new File("/path");
File[] arr = new File[arrayList.size()];

for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ )
    arr[i] = new File(parent, arrayList.get(i));

// Now arr will contain File objects in the order they are listed in arrayList
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to convert your array to a list using the *Arrays.asList* method. Then you can sort your array list using *Collections.sort(yourNewArrayList)*:

```
List<File> sortedFileArrayList = Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(new File("/path").listFiles()));
```

However, if you only need your array sorted without being converted to a list (as list conversion is not necessary for sorting) you can use

```
Arrays.sort(new File("/path").listFiles());
```

instead.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP wants the folders sorted in the order given by an other array.